# SQL how to inner join based on a condition

Tags: sql, plsql

I have two tables - one called customers consisting of the fields id, name and referrals and another table called devices consisting of the fields id and type - where type is either 'mobile' or 'laptop'. The id field in the devices table corresponds to the id of a customer in the customers table. Note one customer can have 2 entries in the devices table if they have used both a mobile and a laptop.

I'm trying to query something which returns a persons 'name', the devices they have used (lets call this 'devices_used') and 'referrals' where 'name' and 'referrals' come from the customers table and 'devices_used' is as follows: when a customer ONLY has a mobile entry in the devices table then this field should be populated as 'mobile', when ONLY laptop then this should be 'laptop' but if a client has both a mobile and laptop entry in the devices table then this should be populated as 'both'.

I'm not really sure how to do this as something like

```
select c.name, d.type, c.referrals 
from customers c 
inner join devices d on c.id = d.id
```

isn't what I'm looking for since this would return two rows for the same customer if they have used both a mobile and a laptop - I'm looking for a query which which return just one row per customer and in the case they have used both devices the 'devices_used' field should be populated as 'both'.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data / desired results is a good addition to any SQL question

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions, I believe you could simply use a GROUP BY to deduplicate what you are looking for.

```
select c.name, d.type, c.referrals 
from customers c 
inner join devices d on c.id = d.id
group by c.name, d.type, c.referrals
```

Alternatives might include looking at your channel (device used) one at a time and using a UNION to put them back together, but it depends on your goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH device_numbers AS (
     SELECT c.id,
           COUNT(d.type) AS num_devices
     FROM customers c
     JOIN devices d
     ON c.id = d.id
     GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT c.name, 
     CASE WHEN num_devices = 2 THEN 'both'
     ELSE d.type END AS devices_used
FROM customers c
JOIN devices d
ON c.id = d.id
JOIN device_numbers dn
ON c.id = dn.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need to aggregate your *devices* table, you can easily do this by *applying* it for each customer.

The following makes some guesses you may need to amend as appropriate, eg catering for NULL values

```
select c.name, d.[type], c.referrals 
from customers c 
outer apply (
  select case when Count(*)=1 then Max([type]) else 'both' end
    from devices d
    where d.id = c.id
    group by d.id
)d([type]);
```